# How to use ~> and <~ in grammar rule definition in Scala?

Tags: scala, dsl

How can I ignore all strings in these grammar rules using correct placement of ~> or <~ operators?

```
def typeDefBody = ident ~ ":" ~ ident ~ "{" ~ fieldBody ~ "}"

def fieldBody = "validation" ~ "{" ~ validationBody ~ "}"

def validationBody = length ~ pattern

def length = "length" ~ "=" ~ wholeNumber ~ "to" ~ wholeNumber

def pattern = "pattern" ~ "=" ~ stringLiteral
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I should break `typeDefBody` to 3 None terminal rules as below

```
def typeDefBody =  ident ~ typeDefBodySequence1

def typeDefBodySequence1 = ":" ~> ident ~ typeDefBodySequence2

def typeDefBodySequence2 = "{" ~> fieldBody <~ "}"

def fieldBody = "validation" ~ "{" ~> validationBody <~ "}"

def validationBody = length ~ pattern

def length = "length" ~ "=" ~> wholeNumber ~ "to" ~ wholeNumber

def pattern = "pattern" ~ "=" ~> stringLiteral
```

Comment: Or use parentheses: `def typeDefBody = (ident <~ ":") ~ ident ~ ("{" ~> fieldBody <~ "}")`